# Regex validation in Javascript email

Tags: javascript, regex, javascript-objects

I am doing a validation which looks like this in the following format:

```
function validateEmail(email) 
{
    var re = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

this works absolutely fine for the email with the following format : `abc@example.com`.
I need to validate the email with the following format , `g-something@example.com`
I tried this:

```
function validateEmail(email) 
{
    var re = g-/\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

But its not validating exactly . Any modifications for this?

Comment: [Your regex works as it is. Missing anchors, `^` and `$`.](https://regex101.com/r/hB5gK3/1) `\S` matches any non-space characters, `g-` are also a _non-space_ characters.

Answer (score 2):

Move `g-` to regex, also add `^` and `$` to match with entire string

```js
function validateEmail(email) 
{
    var re = /^g-\S+@\S+\.\S+$/;
    return re.test(email);
}

console.log(validateEmail('test@gmail.com'));
console.log(validateEmail('g-test@gmail.com'));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting a parser error in the character "@"

Comment: I am using a huge application ,In the index.cshtml file , in the <script> function validate(email) { var re = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/; } . So, when the application is run there is parser error in this line , Message : "\" is not a valid start of a code block.

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateEmail(email) 
{
    var re = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

this regex should work for what you need. Found on [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

If you want to see what it does, [this tool is amazing](https://jex.im/regulex/#!embed=false&flags=&re=%5E%5BA-Z0-9._%25%2B-%5D%2B%40%5BA-Z0-9.-%5D%2B%5C.%5BA-Z%5D%7B2%2C%7D%24)